# invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII whith array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to put strings inside an array in rails. My problem is when the elements inside this array are not English it give me this strange page and say this error - 
ArgumentError in UsersController#my_profile

invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

do you know what should i do ??

thanks

Comment: add `#encoding: utf-8` at the beginning of your file?

Comment: where will be the best place to add this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on macOS or Linux, you can start Middleman this way to force it to use UTF-8:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Not sure about Windows, though.